# Custom UIStoryboardSegue for a UINavigationController transition

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I am experimenting with using Storyboard and Segue and am looking to abstract the responsibilities of the segue from the view controllers. I know that the best way to do this would be to subclass a UIStoryboardSegue class and use that as a custom segue; But ... I only get the 'not applicable' message in the attributes window when I try to convert my segue to a custom type. This, I believe is because the View Controller has a Navigation controller attached to it and this dictates the segue. So my question is ...

How does it handle segue transitions within a navigation controller and is there a way for me to override these methods and use a custom segue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering an old question, but I came across it in a Google search.

You need to subclass UINavigationController and implement `-segueForUnwindingToViewController:fromViewController:identifier:`

See here for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16844573/891910